# How to apply '"' inside of variable?

Tags: angular

Goal:
Use variable b containing data in order to show  the screen's message "Got the JWT as: 123"

Problem:
In order to reduce the hard coding and apply variable I was not enable to retrieve the requested result.

How do you apply the symbol '"' inside of a of the variable b?

Info:
Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-x17ard?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Thank you

---

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  /** 
  navigate() {
    this.router.navigate(["authenticate"], { queryParams: { jwt: "123" } });
  }

  */

  navigate() {
    let a = "authenticate";
    let b = "jwt: 123";

    this.router.navigate([a], { queryParams: { b } });
  }
}
```

---

```
<a [routerLink]="['/authenticate']" [queryParams]="{ jwt: '123'}">Authenticate</a> | <a routerLink="/home">Home</a> | 

<button (click)="navigate()">Navigate to Authenticate</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Why not just use `'` as string wrappers and then use " where you want them, such as `'"Your string goes here!"'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply the symbol" ? I guess `let b = '"';` does not solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work to use ' instead of ". I have already tried it. You need to use " but how do I apply this symbol inside of  variable that is already using ". You have review and then tes the code in order to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do this, is to create a helper function:

```
qoute(s: string):string{
return `"${s}"`
```

}

now you can just use it like this:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
  params => {
    this.jwt =  this.qoute(params['jwt']);
  }
)
```

see the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-qnuspw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauthentication%2Fauthentication.component.ts)

if you do this often, you may want to create a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#transforming-data-using-pipes)

Comment: The location take place only at app.component.ts

Comment: Which location?

Comment: That one that is located at app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

`b` would need to be defined as follows, you need the double `"` around the `key` as well as the `value`.

```
let b = '"jwt": "123"';
```

Then you will have to expand your logic in `authentication.component.ts` to handle both formats, your template route is one standard and your `b` variable is another.

- Important to note that using variable b in your route creates an
  object using `b` as the key for the key value pair.
- You will need to access it via `params.b` to retrieve the string literal, then
  construct back into a `JSON Object` for dot notation.

  ```
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     console.log("normal params: ", params);
     let _jwt;
     if (params.b) {
       console.log("params.b: ", params.b);
       // add encapsulating {} to parse into JSON Object
       const jObj = JSON.parse("{" + params.b + "}");
       console.log("jObj: ", jObj);
       _jwt = jObj.jwt;
     } else {
       _jwt = params.jwt;
     }
     this.jwt = _jwt;
   });
  ```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-yr1fg2?file=src/app/authentication/authentication.component.ts